# Margin-bottom editing header?

Tags: html, navbar

I'm trying to make the #navbar lower so it seems to hanging off the edge of the header, but whenever I edit it to go down, it just makes the header go lower. How can I only make the navigation bar go lower so that it seems to hang off the edge of the header?

Code:

http://www.codecademy.com/courseBlaster14854_53a1c3f8631fe99231000802_deleted_53a1c3f8631fe99231000802_deleted/codebits/gioGOU/edit

Answer (score 0):

Without moving element out of the flow maybe doing something like:

remove border radius and background from header and give the h1 a class, move following css there:

```
h1.heading{
  background-color: #3c4543;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

remove css from header

```
#header {
  position: relative;
}
```

swap heading and navbar:

```
<div id="header">
<h1 class="heading" align="center", style="font-family:cursive"><font size="7">Risebush</font></h1>
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href=#">Home</li>
<li><a href=#">About Us</li>
<li><a href=#">Become a Member</li>
<li><a href=#">Contact Us</li>
<li><a href=#">Games</li>
<li><a href=#">Movies</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#navbar{
padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

navbar is inside the header. So the `padding` determines the distance from header div and not from top(body). Then to lower the distance between navbar and the text, decrease margin-bottom. Set the pixel value to anything you want. I set it to 50

Also, if you want the header to not go above the page and be visible. Change

```
#header{
top:0;
}
```